# Pentaho keetle - Create file depending on values

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I've got a table in my database that I would like to export in different files depending on a specific name (let say scientific_name - example below). For each scientific name in my table I would like to:

1. create the corresponding file, e.g. `ab.txt`, `ac.txt`
2. insert in this file all the corresponding values.

*Examples*

For `ab.txt`:

```
id, value 
1,  2
3,  3
```

for `ac.txt`:

```
id, value 
2,  5
4,  4
```

Example of my table:

```
id     | scientific_name     | Name        | value
1      |  ab                 | aa          | 2    
2      |  ac                 | cc          | 5 
3      |  ab                 | aa          | 3
4      |  ac                 | cc          | 4
```

Do you have any idea how I could do that?

Thanks a lot

Arnaud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text file output step has an option that allows you to specify a field in the dataset that has the name of the file that's going to be created.

Look at this example:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwwXJ3GUloGURUJqT0RkT3g0SmM/view?usp=sharing

It creates 2 different files depending on the name of the column in the dataset. It's pretty simple, but it shows the functionality you need. Bear in mind, this transformation will output the files directly on kettle's installation folder.

Comment: Hi Carlos,

Thanks for your answer and for the example.
I've finally been able to do it. 
The text output of my exemple was only to present the idea... In fact the desired output was a shapefile (a GIS format). 
By doing a group by and by defining for each of them a filename, I was able to export my file.

Thanks again

Comment: You're welcome Arnaud. You should mark the question as answered (by you).